# Cannot return running IV from EVP_CIPHER_CTX_iv()

Tags: openssl

I'm using Openssl 1.1.1 for some of my work which involved sending encryption data using AES 256 GCM mode. And as an example , I've created a sample struct and then encrypted the data using AES 256 GCM mode. After calling the EVP_EncryptUpdate method, I was trying to get the running IV (or current IV) using EVP_CIPHER_CTX_iv() method and then dumping it to console. But for some reason I'm just getting all 0's as the output something like 00 00 00 00-00 ....

Also I tried to get the original IV using EVP_CIPHER_CTX_original_iv() and even this is giving me all 0's which is quite different from the original IV used to create the cipher context.

Thanks

Example code,

```
auto context = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
if (context != nullptr) {
   if (EVP_EncryptInit_ex(
         context, EVP_aes_256_gcm(), nullptr,
          reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(key.c_str()),
          reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(iv.c_str())) != 1) {
            std::cerr << "Failed to init encryption cipher context with AES 256 GCM encryption mode";
            return -1;
        }
    }
const unsigned char *orig_iv = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_original_iv(context);

BIO_dump_fp(stderr, (const char*)EVP_CIPHER_CTX_original_iv(context), EVP_CIPHER_CTX_iv_length(context));

BIO_dump_fp(stderr, (const char*)EVP_CIPHER_CTX_iv(context), EVP_CIPHER_CTX_iv_length(context));
```

The above program outputs the following for the running IV and original IV
**0000 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00               ............**

Is there anything wrong in the above code ? How do I get the original IV and print it so that I can compare it with the one I used to init the context ?